# TypeError: IPFS is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs, orbitdb

I'm trying to use Orbit-DB, So I follow [the guide](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/blob/master/GUIDE.md). But at the [*Create a database step*](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/blob/master/GUIDE.md#create-a-database), I get an error:

```
const ipfs = new IPFS()
             ^

TypeError: IPFS is not a constructor
```

Here is my full code:

```js
const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const OrbitDB = require('orbit-db')

// Create IPFS instance
const ipfs = new IPFS()
ipfs.on('ready', async () => {
  const orbitdb = await OrbitDB.createInstance(ipfs)
  const db = await orbitdb.docs('opews-db-test1')
  const address = db.address
})
```

I checked that there was no error in the `require()` with a `console.log()`, but it seems not. So I don't know how to fix that...

Comment: What version of `ipfs` have you installed?

Comment: Can you try using `const ipfs = await IPFS.create()` instead of `const ipfs = new IPFS()`?

Comment: I use the 0.43.3. The code that you gave return me an error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: Can you try without the `await`? Like so: `const ipfs = IPFS.create()`?

Comment: The error left! But now I have the error `TypeError: ipfs.on() isn't a function`

Comment: Could you try out the code in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPFS has changed the way you construct an IPFS node, can you try this code:

```js
const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const OrbitDB = require('orbit-db')

async function main() {
  const ipfs = await IPFS.create();
  const orbitdb = await OrbitDB.createInstance(ipfs);
  const db = await orbitdb.docs('opews-db-test1');
  const address = db.address;
}

main();
```

Comment: Something is generated (I get `to get started, enter: jsipfs cat /ipfs/.../readme` and 3 `Swarm listening on`), but I always get `(node:32691) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: ipfs.on is not a function`, besides `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.`

Comment: I've updated my code, it's not using the `on` function anymore. Could you retry with the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

A whole example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>IPFS in the Browser</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ipfs/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/orbit-db/dist/orbitdb.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
(async function main()
{
  node = await Ipfs.create({
  repo: "ipfs/shared",
  config: {"Bootstrap": ["/ipv4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4002/ws/ipfs/<your go-ipfs peer id>"]},
  EXPERIMENTAL: {pubsub: true }});

    console.log('Online status: ', node.isOnline() ? 'online' : 'offline')
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML= 'Node status: ' + (node.isOnline() ? 'online' : 'offline')
    
    orbit = await OrbitDB.createInstance(node);


    docs = await orbit.docs('my-docs', { indexBy: 'name' })
    hash = await docs.put({name: 'shamb0t', followers: 500 })
    console.log(hash)
    console.log(docs.get('shamb0t')[0].followers)


    feed = await orbit.feed('my-feed');
    hash = await feed.add('hello');
    console.log(hash);
    console.log(feed.iterator({ limit: -1 }).collect()[0].payload.value)

//feed.del(hash)    
})()
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
  <h1 id="status">Node status: offline</h1>

 
</body>
</html>
```